# Матрас или матрац?

Tags: лексика

Как правильно писать "матрас" или "матрац"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В современном русском языке принята форма "матрас", а "матрац" является устаревшей. Однако обе эти формы одинаково верны.

Answer (score 1):

В словаре Ожегова  написано и то и другое